# Facebook like (button count) not visible on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I have followed the exact steps given on facebook developer website, which is to add JS sdk after opening body tag(ideally) and placing the div at the desired place where button should appear.

```
<body>
<!-- Facebook like button js -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

 <!-- Add this where you want the button to appear -->
 <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myWebsite" data-width="400" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>

   </body>
```

After doing this, it would still not show up.

Comment: a test link would be important

Comment: How do i make a test link?

Comment: well...don´t you have a server where this is running?

Comment: well, i guess that´s the problem then, see my answer

Comment: No, I am trying to build a site .. the html runs on my browser

Comment: Why the button doesn't show up surprises me as other such buttons(twitter and g+1) are visible.

Comment: will this help?  http://jsfiddle.net/xtLk8s4r/1/

Comment: it is not surprising, check out my answer. other buttons may load the sdks with http/https already. if you omit it, the browser will use the protocol of the website - and since you don´t have a server, there is no protocol.

Comment: no, this is just the same code. again, check out my answer and try my suggestion.

Comment: Well, its disappointing that i have to make a server for this. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button: says to put JS after opening body tag and div for button where I want to see it. I did everything as mentioned in the steps. Why cant i see it on my browser?

Comment: you don´t have to. again, read my answer and try my code change. that´s a well known error.

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t run this code on a server (localhost or remote), you need to change the following line:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
```

..to this one:

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
```

I highly suggest NOT doing that though, and using a server on localhost for testing/development.

If that code change does not work, upload it to a real server (without the code change). I just tested it and it works perfectly fine. You should really consider using a real server (or a local one) for development.

Use an editor like [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) or [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), they all include a server. For example, Brackets is pretty easy for "live editing".

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button: says "js.src" is used to adjusting language and for localization purpose.

Comment: that´s the source of the javascript sdk. only "en_US" you can change, to choose another language. again, try the code. add https:

Comment: Ok, it is getting hard for me to understand, what code should i change/write so that that facebook (like-count) button is visible on my browser while running the html file without using any server?

Comment: thanks for your time, did not help me solve my issue!

Comment: then check out your browser console for warnings or errors.

Comment: just tested it on a real server and it worked perfectly fine: http://www.devils-heaven.com/extern/test.html

Comment: using the facebook stuff without any server is not worth it, you really should consider using a server.

Comment: WARNING: Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.Received message of type object from https://platform.twitter.com, expected a string. fb:like failed to resize in 45s

Comment: yeah, i saw that. read my answer again, i added more information.

Comment: Making a server seems to be the only option left. Will try!

Comment: it is the best option anyway. developing without a (local) server is so last year ;)

Comment: you can, but xampp is pretty heavy. if you need php/mysql, then it may be a good choice though. if not, you can just use brackets, it´s free and includes a server.

Comment: Tried it out on brackets. The button still doesn't show up?

Comment: did you use "https" and start the brackets server with the flash sign? (right side of brackets)